# синхронное выполнение метода

Tags: node.js

при старте сервера Node.js получаю ошибку

> (node:2320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'sync' of undefined

в файле запуска

```
const specs = require('./swagger')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const config = require('../config/config')
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs.default))

require('./passport')
require('./routes')(app)

async function fn () {
    const { sequelize } = await require('./models')
    await sequelize.sync({ force: false })
        .then(() => {
            app.listen(config.development.port)
            console.log(`Server started on port ${config.development.port}`)
        })
}

// Вызов fn
fn().then(module.exports = app)
```

файл в котором содержатся настройки sequelize из папки './models'

```
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.development.database,
    config.development.username,
    config.development.password,
    {
        dialect: config.development.dialect,
        host: config.development.host
    }
)

const klaw = require('klaw')
const through2 = require('through2')

const excludeDirFilter = through2.obj(function (item, enc, next) {
    if (!item.stats.isDirectory()) this.push(item)
    next()
})

async function fn () {
    await klaw(__dirname)
        .pipe(excludeDirFilter)
        .on('data', item => {
            if (path.basename(item.path) !== 'index.js') {
                const model = sequelize.import(item.path)
                db[model.name] = model
            }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log(1)
        })

    await Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
        if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
            db[modelName].associate(db)
            console.log(2)
        }
    })

    db.sequelize = sequelize
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize
}

// Вызов fn
fn().then(module.exports = db)
```

История началась с того что мне нужно получить список всех файлов папке и подпапках models, для этого использовал npm -i klaw. Но затем как я понимаю время выполнения рекурсивного поиска стало занимать больше времени поэтому попробовал использовать async/await. Что привело к текущей ошибке. Тема для меня новая и пока с трудом понимаемая. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `fn().then(module.exports = db)` -> `module.exports  = fn().then(()=> db)`

Comment: после изменения экспорта ошибка изменилась

`(node:5764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Iskander\WebstormProjects\farma\farmer\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:139:34)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Iskander\WebstormProjects\farma\farmer\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:174:10)
    at app (C:\Users\Iskander\WebstormProjects\farma\farmer\server\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:39:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)`

Comment: тут уже в коде где-то ошибка, нужно отлаживать на каком из шагов падает

Comment: добавь catch к функциям и посмотри какая на самом деле ошибка